# How to overlay multiple ggplots in geom_sf with appropriate layout of plot title and legends?

Tags: r, ggplot2, layout

I have three data sets built from `geom_sf()` in `sf` package:

**Base Map**
[image: Base map]
**Polygon to be overlayed to Base Map**
[image: Polygon to be overlayed to Base map]
**Point to be overlayed to Base Map**
[image: Point to be overlayed to Base map]

What I need to do are:
- Overlaying polygon and point data (2nd and 3rd map) on Base Map (1st map)
- Laying out legend of each map on the right side of the plot in three rows
- Putting a title on top-left position of the plot

The desired output seems something like this:
[image]

Challenges are::
 - I could make overlaying map using the scripts described below; however I cannot put legends on the right side of the plot
 - Though I still cannot plot legends in the desired layout, but it may be a problem to adjust the size of each legend to fit into the layout
 - I also need to `ggsave` the plot, however layout using `grid` package may no support this function according to [this post](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/egg/vignettes/Ecosystem.html)
 - It will be an issue how to adjust the position of the title overlapping the image not to waste space in the entire plot. I mean, as the bas map has white space on top-left, it is good to adjust the position of the title. I can make it if I only plot the base map. However, to keep the same scale between three maps, I need to remove title and legend from each map and make them together overlapped firthe, then need to put title and legend separately.

Currently, I am using following scripts to overlay three maps:

```
pushViewport(viewport(layout=grid.layout(3,2)))
vplayout <- function(x, y) viewport(layout.pos.row=x,layout.pos.col=y)
             plot(map1+theme(legend.position="none",plot.title=element_blank()),vp=vplayout(1:3,1))
plot(map2+theme(legend.position="none"),vp=vplayout(1:3,1))
plot(map3+theme(legend.position="none"),vp=vplayout(1:3,1))
# Following scripts do not work well as it removes previous plot
plot(c.leg,vp=vplayout(1,2)) 
plot(a.leg,vp=vplayout(2,2))
plot(e.leg,vp=vplayout(3,2))
```

I can make a plot overlaying three maps, however I cannot put legends and title in my desired way. Do you have any suggestions?

===== ADDITIONAL TEST USING NEW_SCALE() =====
As suggested by @alistaire I have tried to use `new_scale` function; however, it brings an output looks like this:

[image]

I simply followed an example [here](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale). Colors in the actual plot seems okay but legend colors in the previous two plots becames gray. I am wondering if this function supports `geom_sf()`. The script that I applied is shown below:

```
ggplot() +
  ## Street
  geom_sf(data=street,color="gray") +
  ## Building
  geom_sf(data=bld,color="gray",fill="white") +
  ## Centerline
  geom_sf(data=cent.clst,aes(color=eval(as.name(field[i])),fill=eval(as.name(field[i])))) +
    ## Appearance
      # Title
      labs(
        # Main title
        title=title[i],
        # Legend title
        color="Cluster",fill="Cluster") +   
      # Color of legend
      scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1") + scale_fill_brewer(palette="Set1") +

  ## New scale
  new_scale_color() + new_scale_fill() +

  ## Activity
  geom_sf(data=act,aes(color=act2_name,fill=act2_name)) +
      ## Color
      scale_color_manual(values=col) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=col) +
      ## Legend title
      labs(color="Activity name",fill="Activity name") +

  ## New scale
  new_scale_color() + new_scale_fill() +

  ## Entrance
  geom_sf(data=ent,aes(color=label,fill=label),size=0.1) +
      ## Legend title
      labs(color="Entrance type",fill="Entrance type") +
      ## Color
      scale_color_manual(values=as.vector(glasbey(30))) +
      scale_fill_manual(values=as.vector(glasbey(30))) +

  ## Appearance
    # Theme
    theme_bw() + 

    theme(
    # Remove grid and border
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.border = element_blank(),
    # Remove axis
    axis.text.x=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
    axis.text.y=element_blank(),
    axis.ticks.y=element_blank(),
    # Delete margin: top, right, bottom, and left
    plot.margin=margin(0.5,0,0,0,"cm"),
    legend.margin=margin(0,0,0,0,"cm"),
    legend.box.margin=margin(0,0,0,0,"cm"),
    # Adjust position of legend and title: c(0,0)=left-bottom, c(1,1)=right-top
    plot.title=element_text(vjust=-10,hjust=0.05),
    legend.position=c(0.85,0.89))
```

Comment: Why not call `geom_sf` three times with different data in the same plot and let ggplot handle the alignment? Color scales may be a pain, but [ggnewscale](https://github.com/eliocamp/ggnewscale) offers a way around that

Comment: Thanks, I agree with your idea as it is the simplest solution, however, I have already tried to use `new_scale` function but it brong undesired result as explained in the post additionally.